# Golang untyped int overflow on 32-bit arm

Tags: linux, go, arm, embedded-linux, cgo

I am trying to create a switch on a 32-bit signed integer returned from a C function. This is all being compiled for a 32-bit arm system via: `GOARCH=arm GOOS=linux CC="..." go build`

My code is:

```golang
func ResultToString(value C.int) error {
    switch int(value) {
    case 1:
        return nil
    case -1:
        return fmt.Errorf("Unknown")
    case 0xF3210123:
        return fmt.Errorf("Line high")
    }
    return fmt.Errorf("bad value")
}
```

The error I am receiving is: `pkg/app/conversions.go:200:7: 0xF3210123 (untyped int constant 4079026467) overflows int`

`0xF3210123` in decimal is `4_079_026_467` and fits completely in 32-bits as `1111 0011 0010 0001 0000 0001 0010 0011`. However, this is the unsigned representation, when I want the signed one (which is `-215_940_829`).

I have tried to convert it in the switch but all my methods are not working (here tried on constant `0xF3210124`:

- `case int(0xF3210124):` gives error `cannot convert 0xF3210124 (untyped int constant 4079026468) to type int`

I've also tried creating it as a regular `var` and casting that way as described in this blog post: https://go.dev/blog/constants but that isn't working either:

```golang
# Source
var testVal = 0xF3210123
...
case int(testVal):
```

```
# Error
cannot use 0xF3210123 (untyped int constant 4079026467) as int value in variable declaration (overflows)
```

I want to use the literals directly to match the specification I am trying to implement. Is there a way to do this easily that I'm just missing?

--

What DOES work is using the converted constant (shown below). However, I have a lot of these codes and again want to use the hex literal for easy spec matching.

```golang
# Working example
func ResultToString(value C.int) error {
    switch int(value) {
    case 1:
        return nil
    case -1:
        return fmt.Errorf("Unknown")
    case -215_940_829:
        return fmt.Errorf("Line high")
    }
    return fmt.Errorf("bad value")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be explained with a particular interpretation of the language spec about untyped constants. It looks like `0xF3210123` is interpreted as an `uint32` value, which then causes overflow when converted to a `int32` value at compile time.

But it does not do that when converted at runtime.

So ugly, but a workaround could be (i did not test this on a 32-bit system):

```
var v = 0xF3210124
var x = int32(v)

...

switch ... {
   case x: ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I also tried a few things... this one worked:

```
const (
        ZERO int32 = 0
        BIG1 = 0xF3210123
        BIG2 = 0xFF00FF00
)
```

and later:

```
    case BIG1:
        fmt.Printf("big\n");
```

It sounds like you'll have to come up with lots of names, but some folks would say that's better than having lots of unknown constants everywhere.

Comment: This one is not working - gives error: `F3210123 (untyped int constant 4079026467) overflows int32` from `const (
 ZERO         int32 = 0
 F3210123       = 0xF3210123
)` - I also tried it with a constant like `BIG1` instead of `F3210123` with the same issue

Comment: Very strange. It works here on go 1.19. Here's the whole source. package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

const (
        ZERO int32 = iota
        F3210123 = 0xF3210123
        FF00FF00 = 0xFF00FF00
)

func main() {
    x := F3210123
    switch int(x) {
    case FF00FF00:
        fmt.Printf("FF00\n");
    default:
        fmt.Printf("other %x\n", x);
    }
    fmt.Printf("ZERO %d  F321 %x FF00 %x\n", ZERO, F3210123, FF00FF00)
}

Comment: @aMike code in comments aren't readable. You need to include the code in the question itself or give the full running example in https://go.dev/play/

Comment: you don't see an error because you use `int` and compile for a 64-bit platform. If you compile 32-bit code or change `int` to `int32` you'll see the error immediately: https://go.dev/play/p/lmw3g8M1Jl3